# Trying to prove $Ae=\lambda e$ to show $\lambda$ is eigenvalue and $e$ is eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The background comes follows:

First, the question defined function $f(v)=(Av,v)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A$ is symmetric (in fact I deduced it from another condition, not shown here), $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The length of a vector is $|\cdot|$. Now given a set $S=\{v:|v|=1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $f$ could take its maximum value on $S$ since the set $S$ is compact and $f$ is continuous.

The maximum value is denoted by $\lambda$, $e$ is the vector in $S$ which is the maximum value point i.e. $f(e)=\lambda$. Define another set $V=\{v:(v,e)=0\}$ which is orthogonal to $e$.

Now, for any $v\in V$, the equation $(Ae,v)=0$ is always satisfied. I want to show there exists $Ae=\lambda e$ such that $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$ and $e$ is eigenvector.

By the knowledge of Rayleigh's quotient I did know $\lambda$ is the maximum eigenvalue of matrix $A$, but I hope to prove it without using Rayleigh's quotient. I found I had difficulty in proving $e$ is the eigenvector correspond to $\lambda$.

Comment: Think about Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @TedShifrin It works! Nice hint.